# Meteor observeChanges return multiple cursor

Tags: meteor, meteor-publications

Publisher:

```
Meteor.publish('market', function(limit) {
  let self = this;

  Markets.find({}, {
    limit: limit
  }).observeChanges({
    added: function(id, market){
      self.added("market", id, market);

      let country = findCountry(market);
      self.added("countries", country._id, country);
    }
  });

  return self.ready();

});
```

Above publisher works fine. What my issue is the above publisher publish `market` and relevant `countries` cursor. Market cursor has limit. Now I want to publish market cursor with limit and `observeChanges` in `country` should run without limit.

So I have written like

```
Meteor.publish('market', function() {
  let self = this;

  let markets = Markets.find({}, {
    limit: limit
  });

  Markets.find().observeChanges({
    added: function(id, market) {

      let country = findCountry(market);
      self.added("countries", country._id, country);
    }
  });

  return [self.ready(), markets]; // How to publish multiple cursors??

});
```

How to publish multiple cursors?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good use of the [reywood:publish-composit](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) package. It handles all of the logic for related documents when a new record is added, updated, or removed.

I'm not sure what the logic is in your `findCountry` function, but I imagine it would be something line this:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('market', {
    find: function() {
        return Markets.find({}, {limit: limit});
    },
    children: [
        {
            find: function(market) {
                return Countries.find({countryCode: market.countryCode});
            }
        }
    ]
});
```